# sqlce auto increment ids not generated when using dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-server-ce

i'm writing a program which uses  sql compact edition. 
in this program i would like to load one-many related data using the dataset class functionality. 
after loading, the data can be shown on the form, and adapted by the user. no problems, when using sqlceDataAdapter the data will be written to disk successfully.

But... i would like to add new data as well, so add data in the parent table, and data in the child table. These data will be added to the dataset first. After that i would like to write it to the database when the user wants to save the new data. To add data in the child table i need to know the id of the parent data, and there's the problem ! the id is specified as integer, auto incremented, and when adding data to the dataset, the id is not generated automatically.

when writing data to the database, the ids are filled in by sqlce, but i need these ids already before, when creating the child ids.

anybody an idea how solve this, without generating the ids myself ?

thanks !

Comment: What version, do you use Adapter and Adaptermanager? What does the CommandText of the Select command look like?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to resort to @@identity in your insert command of the dataset